# Cannot install Molch EncFS Manager from tar.gz because ./configure file does not exist

Tags: make, tar

I've been trying to install something from a tar.gz file but it just doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 20.04. I followed all the instructions to the T but when I run `./configure` it says "No such file or directory". Here is what happens:

```
cd ~/EncFS/MolchEncfsManager-19.06
bhaskar@Machine:~/EncFS/MolchEncfsManager-19.06$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, which 'instructions' do you refer to?  The tar.gz file for Molch EncFS Manager says to use `qmake` as my answer says, and not autoconf / `configure`.

Answer (score 3):

### try NOT to use encFS as it has [reasonable security problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS#EncFS_1.8_security_concerns), you are better off with luks or gocryptfs

[image: Bart doesn't encFS]

Answer (score 1):

So according to the `INSTALL` file within the tarball for the software Molch Encfs Manager that you're using (downloaded from [here](https://moritzmolch.com/apps/mencfsm/index.html)), you actually need `qmake` and the Qt dependencies installed to build/install this.  It does not use `autoconf` or a `./configure` file to configure itself.

You simply use `qmake` (which you may need to install - `sudo apt install qt5-qmake`) on the source directory and the Qt make system will handle build/install steps.

This may need additional dependencies in Qt though, at which point you have to track down which packages you'll need to install.  (But that's going to be different for each software you look at, and the deps aren't listed clearly here for this specific encfs manager)

**THIS SAID** you should avoid using encfs if you can - there's a lot of reasonable security concerns over it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me on how to actually install using qmake? Like what commands I need to run after I install qmake?

Comment: @user178834 Unfortunately, their INSTALL instructions just say to run `qmake` - the way I understand that is that would be everything you need, there's no additional instructions available for that piece of software.